# Which Python exception to throw when restricting class to at most one instance?

Tags: python, exception, singleton

Which of the built-in Python exceptions should be used to signal that an instance of my class (e.g. `MCWindow`) has already been created?  It would follow something like this:

```
window = MCWindow()
try:
    aWindow = MCWindow()
except DontMakeAnotherOneOfTheseInstancesException:
    print("Whoops") # Always the best way to handle exceptions :)
```

The singleton pattern would probably be more suitable here, but I'd still like to know about whether or not there is a built-in Exception for this case.

Comment: There is no built in exception for this, because this is a not a useful or meaningful thing to do/signal, because such a restriction is usually pointless and when it isn't there are better ways to enforce it. **Why** do you have to enforce that only one instance is created?

Comment: RuntimeError is used "when an error is detected that doesn’t fall in any of the other categories", that's the builtin exception that fits best. But using a custom exception is probably better, or not using singletons at all like others mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singleton pattern is not very common in `python`. Usually, modules are used instead of object instances.

In other words, there is no accurate built-in exception for this. Create your own, or switch to modules.

*Note: it is possible, using a bit of metaprogramming, to create a class that when instantiated will always return the same object, no exceptions involved.*

Comment: I'm not sure if using a module for my `MCWindow` would be ideal for my case, but it's a good suggestion for future projects.  Metaprogramming with Python is a bit beyond my scope for now, but thanks.

Comment: @uʍop ǝpısdn, I've done some tweak without the need for metaprogramming, check my answer in this page

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it, with a little tweak

```
# python object singleton

class Observer():
    pass
observe = Observer()

class singleton():          
    def __init__(self,):            
        if observe.__dict__.has_key(self.__class__.__name__):
            raise Exception, 'Only one instance of the same "%s" class is allowed' % self.__class__.__name__
        observe.__dict__[self.__class__.__name__]=True
    def some_method(self,):
        # roll your own code
        pass


one = singleton()        
two = singleton()     # will raise an error
```

The observer class is where you store the state, and singleton class, is the class in request which is the one you want to restrict it to one instance only, you can create many classes like the `singleton`, but only one `Observer` to keep the state of all of them.

Try the above code and have fun .. it works with me :))

---

**Update -- Creating singleton without raising exceptions**

```
class Observer():  

    def __init__(self,):     
        self.error = None

    def __setattr__(self,class_name,instance):
        if not self.__dict__.has_key(instance.__class__.__name__):          
            self.__dict__[class_name]=instance
        else:
            self.error =  'You are only allowed to creat intance once'

    def __getattr__(self,class_name):
        if self.__dict__.has_key(class_name):
            return self.__dict__[class_name]
        else:
            return None
```

And this is your class to be instantiated as singleton

```
class test():
    pass
```

*Usage*

```
observe = Observer()  

observe.test = test() # This will be created and bound to the variable
observe.test = test() # This will not be created nor bound, but will generate an error msg in observe.error

if not observe.error:
    print 'created successfully'
else:
    print 'Encountered a problem: %s, only this instance has been created: %s' % (observe.error,observe.test)
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort made here to help implement a singleton pattern.  However, I don't think raising an `Exception` is the best option, since it would make it harder to handle the exception because a coder would have to catch all `Exception`s and then figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @SimonT, Check my last update to create a singleton without raising exceptions .. Let me know if it helps

Comment: I believe that your given code merits much credit.  However, as my question was regarding built-in Python Exceptions, and less about the Singleton pattern, I can't really give much other credit.  I will make the most of your solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.
You probably could use RuntimeError or your own inherited exception.
[Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) you could find a list of all built-in exceptions with their descriptions.

Although, as you said, googling for "python singleton" would give you many better solutions.